# Setting TTL on outgoing UDP packets?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, udp, ip

How do I set Time-To-Live socket option in C/C++ on Windows, Mac, and Linux using  using the C/C++ standard libraries? It needs to work without Boost. Either C or C++ is fine. IP header modification for outgoing UDP packets. No multicast.

Answer (score 12):

Basically this is done via the standard `setsockopt`. You need to use the `IPPROTO_IP` level and the option is `IP_TTL`.

I couldn't find a link for this on gnu.org, but (for example..) on freebsd you have [this](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ip&sektion=4&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.1-RELEASE) manual page.

Use:

```
int ttl = 60; /* max = 255 */
setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TTL, &ttl, sizeof(ttl));
```

Comment: Should work with standard C library, in any compatible platform