# How to specify TTL with kernel sock_sendmsg()?

Tags: c, linux-device-driver

I'm using [sock_sendmsg()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.189/source/net/socket.c#L627) in a Linux kernel module (character device driver) to send a UDP packet.

[Network Programming in the Kernel](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7660) is a good reference.

I'd like to set the TTL value but cannot find any reference on how to do that.  Any suggestions?

Here's the send code:

```
static int
sendUdpPkt(struct TClientInfo *client, char *udpPayload, size_t udpLen)
{
    if (verbose)
        printk(KERN_INFO MODULE_NAME": [Client %d] sendUdpPkt - WILL SEND %zu bytes to 0x%X : %hd\n",
            client->clientId, udpLen, client->txAddr.sin_addr.s_addr, ntohs(client->txAddr.sin_port));

    mm_segment_t   oldfs;
    int            bytesSent = 0;
    struct msghdr        msg = {};
    struct iovec      ioData = {};

    if (client->txSock->sk == NULL)
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO MODULE_NAME": [Client %d] sendUdpPkt - Error 'sk' is null\n", client->clientId);
        return 0;
    }

    ioData.iov_base = udpPayload;
    ioData.iov_len  = udpLen;

    iov_iter_init(&msg.msg_iter, WRITE, &ioData, 1, udpLen);

    msg.msg_flags   = 0;
    msg.msg_name    = &client->txAddr;
    msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    msg.msg_control = NULL;
    msg.msg_controllen = 0;
    msg.msg_control = NULL;

    oldfs = get_fs();
    set_fs(KERNEL_DS);
    bytesSent = sock_sendmsg(client->txSock, &msg);
    set_fs(oldfs);

    if (verbose)
        printk(KERN_INFO MODULE_NAME": [Client %d] sendUdpPkt - Sent %d bytes to 0x%X : %hd. TS FIFO %d PKTS\n",
            client->clientId, bytesSent, client->txAddr.sin_addr.s_addr, ntohs(client->txAddr.sin_port), kfifo_len(&client->pktFifo) );

    return bytesSent;
}
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31066061/setting-ttl-on-outgoing-udp-packets answer your question. `linux-device-driver` is this a linux device driver? It looks like user spce program.

Comment: Thanks but that reference is to user-space.  `sock_sendmsg()` and the code above is part of a character device driver in a kernel module.  I've added a link explaining network I/O from the kernel.

Comment: I _guess_ it's the same, and you should call https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/net.h#L190 and hopefully it goes into https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/ipv4/ip_sockglue.c#L894 . I can't seem to find a kernel example, only https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/net/ethernet/chelsio/inline_crypto/chtls/chtls_main.c#L575 . Try cloning kernel and  `grep -- '->setsockopt'`, maybe there are some usages in kernel.